# Trying to reference /paths from other swagger yaml, getting "No operations defined in spec"

Tags: swagger

I have some swagger file whose location is `~/Drobpox/example/id/arch/artefacts/docs/swagger/swagger.yaml`. Its contents is

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Example
  description: Example
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: https://example.com
    description: Example
paths:
  $ref: '../../../../app/id/files/static/core/docs/swagger.yaml#/paths'
```

What I need is to embed the `/paths` from the other file which is `~/Drobpox/example/id/app/id/files/static/core/docs/swagger.yaml`.

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following message: `No operations defined in spec!`.

Any ideas, please?